# "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed" using AesManaged

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

I'm trying to get simple encryption/decryption working with AesManaged, but I keep getting an exception when trying to close the decryption stream.  The string here gets encrypted and decrypted correctly, and then I get the CryptographicException "Padding was invalid and cannot be removed" after Console.WriteLine prints the correct string.

Any ideas?

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
byte[] rawPlaintext = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("This is annoying!");

using (Aes aes = new AesManaged())
{
  aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
  aes.Key = new byte[128/8];
  aes.IV = new byte[128/8];

  using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(),
                                            CryptoStreamMode.Write))
  {
    cs.Write(rawPlaintext, 0, rawPlaintext.Length);
    cs.FlushFinalBlock();
  }

  ms = new MemoryStream(ms.GetBuffer());
  using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(),
                                            CryptoStreamMode.Read))
  {
    byte[] rawData = new byte[rawPlaintext.Length];
    int len = cs.Read(rawData, 0, rawPlaintext.Length);
    string s = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(rawData);
    Console.WriteLine(s);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The trick is to use `MemoryStream.ToArray()`.
I also changed your code so that it uses the `CryptoStream` to Write, in both encrypting and decrypting.  And you don't need to call `CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()` explicitly, because you have it in a `using()` statement, and that flush will happen on `Dispose()`.  The following works for me.

```
byte[] rawPlaintext = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("This is all clear now!");

using (Aes aes = new AesManaged())
{
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    aes.KeySize = 128;          // in bits
    aes.Key = new byte[128/8];  // 16 bytes for 128 bit encryption
    aes.IV = new byte[128/8];   // AES needs a 16-byte IV
    // Should set Key and IV here.  Good approach: derive them from 
    // a password via Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes 
    byte[] cipherText= null;
    byte[] plainText= null;

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cs.Write(rawPlaintext, 0, rawPlaintext.Length);
        }

        cipherText= ms.ToArray();
    }


    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cs.Write(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);
        }

        plainText = ms.ToArray();
    }
    string s = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(plainText);
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Also, I guess you know you will want to explicitly set the [Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.mode.aspx) of the AesManaged instance, and use [System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx)  to derive the Key and IV from a password and salt.

see also:
- [AesManaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx)

Comment: I had the same problem, but using RijndaelManaged (also symmetric) and had no idea what was happening. Turns out that `MemoryStream.GetBuffer()` was getting an *unflushed* version of the data, and most of the final blocks of data were null, which was messing with my padding. `MemoryStream.ToArray()` gets the real array. Many thanks for this solution!

Comment: This is the best/smallest implementation I have seen so far.

Comment: Good call on `Dispose`. I was calling `ms.ToArray()` before disposing CryptoStream. Moving that line outside of the using fixed it for me.

Comment: oh my days, a million thanks @cheeso ! Writing to crypto stream while decrypting and memoryStream.ToArray().... thanks a million once again! That ends 10 hours of hair pulling!

Answer (score 32):

This exception can be caused by a mismatch of any one of a number of encryption parameters.

I used the [Security.Cryptography.Debug](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/clrsecurity/blob/7250c56ccfd40413e68af755e3de40d00c673431/Wiki/Security.Cryptography.Debug.dll.md) interface to trace all parameters used in the encrypt/decrypt methods.

Finally I found out that my problem was that I set the `KeySize` property after setting the `Key` causing the class to regenerate a random key and not using the key that I was initially set up.

Comment: My problem was also setting KeySize after setting the key, Thanks!

Comment: +1 Thank you so much, I'd vote you up 100 times if I could.  I have spent over a day trying to figure out why I couldn't decrypt properly and it turned out I was setting the key size after the key in the code.

Comment: Is Security.Cryptography.Debug still up to date? It seems to have had no changes since 2010

Answer (score 6):

For whats its worth, I'll document what I faced. I was trying to read the encryptor memory stream before the CryptoStream was closed. I was naive and I wasted a day debugging it.

```
    public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] buffer, byte[] sessionKey, out byte[] iv)
    {
        byte[] encrypted;
        iv = null;
        using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesAlg = new AesCryptoServiceProvider { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 })
        {
            aesAlg.Key = sessionKey;
            iv = aesAlg.IV;
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(sessionKey, iv);

            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    csEncrypt.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    
                    //This was not closing the cryptostream and only worked if I called FlushFinalBlock()
                    //encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray(); 
                }

                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();

                return encrypted;
            }
        }
    }
```

Moving the encryptor memory stream read after the cypto stream was closed solved the problem. As Cheeso mentioned. You don't need to call the `FlushFinalBlock()` if you're using the `using` block.

Comment: WOW MAN, AMAZING!!!, you saved my day, about seven hours trying to figure it out... Really I can't thank you enough

Answer (score 2):

> byte[] rawData = new
>   byte[rawPlaintext.Length];

You need to read the length of the buffer, that probably includes the necessary padding (IIRC, been a few years).

Answer (score 2):

Nobody answered, that actually MemoryStream.GetBuffer returns the allocated buffer, not the real data in this buffer. In this case it returns 256-byte buffer, while it contains only 32 bytes of encrypted data.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, this error can occur if the key/iv is not correctly initialized for decryption. In my case I need to copy key and iv from some larger buffer. Here's what I did wrong:

**Does not work:** (Padding is invalid and cannot be removed)

```
aes.Key = new byte[keySize];
Buffer.BlockCopy(someBuffer, keyOffset, aes.Key, 0, keySize);

aes.IV = new byte[ivSize];
Buffer.BlockCopy(someBuffer, ivOffset, aes.IV, 0, ivSize);
```

**Works:**

```
var key = new byte[keySize];
Buffer.BlockCopy(someBuffer, keyOffset, key, 0, keySize);
aes.Key = key;

var iv = new byte[ivSize];
Buffer.BlockCopy(someBuffer, ivOffset, iv, 0, ivSize);
aes.IV = iv;
```

The OP did not make this mistake, but this might be helpful for others seeing the same error.