# C# 4.0 / Sql Server 2008: Encrypt/decrypt in business layer

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, c#-4.0

I just need some advise here. I need to protected some column data, so I have been googling about encryption in **C# 4.0/Sql server 2008** (not R2).

This is probably what I need:

> "When the data must be protected from sysadmins. Practically, in this
>   scenario it would be best not to use SQL  Server internal encryption
>   and far better to rely exclusively on the middle tier to perform
>   encryption and decryption.  It would be very difficult to protect your
>   data from a determined sysadmin if your keys are stored in SQL
>   Server." Source: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc837966%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

What is the correct approach?

I have tried to save data which was encrypted with [Rijndael](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx) and  to database.

I get error: `Length of the data to decrypt is invalid`

I haven't googled this yet.

Should I continue struggeling with this or should I try to solve this with **CLR** or what?
I just can't find a tutorial which shows me how to encrypt/decrypt in business layer.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

Ok this is what I have so far.
The data is encrypted with Rinjdael as shown before.
It is stored in column

```
TestCrypt (varbinary(255), null)
```

I looks like this in the database:

```
0xF6CA99F5B6BFA1D9A0BD2381177E049E02F381078966195B68A54A5BEC4C
```

It is retrieved with a sp, such as:

```
SELECT cast(s.TestCrypt AS varbinary) AS TestCrypt
```

And in data access layer:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    data.TestCrypt = (byte[])reader["TestCrypt"];
}
```

The error is found in DecryptStringFromBytes at this row

```
plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
```

The error: Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.

Comment: If you post your encrypt/decrypt code, then maybe we could help with the error.  This shouldn't be terribly difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on following article:

[Column Encryption in SQL Server 2008 with Symmetric Keys](http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.com/2010/10/column-encryption-in-sql-server-2008.html)

[Cell level Encryption in SQL server](http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/articles/sql-server-bi/19/cell-level-encryption-in-sql-server)

Comment: Hi and thanks. 
Both url:s shows how to encrypt/decrypt in sql server. 
I need this to happen in business layer in my asp.net web project.

Comment: Okay, I thought that you need encyrption and decryption mechanism in sql server...I'll update the answer.....

Answer (score 0):

As far using Encryption and decryption in business layer, I prefer to use following encryption and decryption method:

```
#region Encryption Decription
public class CryptorEngine
{
/// <summary>
/// Encrypt a string using dual encryption method. Return a encrypted cipher Text
/// </summary>
/// <param name="toEncrypt">string to be encrypted</param>
/// <param name="useHashing">use hashing? send to for extra security</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string Encrypt(string toEncrypt, bool useHashing)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] keyArray;
        byte[] toEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt);

        System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader settingsReader = new AppSettingsReader();
        // Get the key from config file
        string key = (string)settingsReader.GetValue("SecurityKey", typeof(String));
        //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(key);
        if (useHashing)
        {
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
            hashmd5.Clear();
        }
        else
            keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdes.Key = keyArray;
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
        tdes.Clear();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "Invalid";   
    }
}
/// <summary>
/// DeCrypt a string using dual encryption method. Return a DeCrypted clear string
/// </summary>
/// <param name="cipherString">encrypted string</param>
/// <param name="useHashing">Did you use hashing to encrypt this data? pass true is yes</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string Decrypt(string cipherString, bool useHashing)
{
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cipherString))
            return "";
        byte[] keyArray;
        byte[] toEncryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherString);

        System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader settingsReader = new AppSettingsReader();
        //Get your key from config file to open the lock!
        string key = (string)settingsReader.GetValue("SecurityKey", typeof(String));

        if (useHashing)
        {
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
            hashmd5.Clear();
        }
        else
            keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdes.Key = keyArray;
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);

        tdes.Clear();
        return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       return "Invalid";   
    }
}
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Yeah but you can return anything such as Invalid or InCorrecrt from excepton block.........

Comment: (Deleted original comment to add this) How does that even compile with the MS compilers? `catch (Exception ex) { }` -- the function never returns a defined value if an exception is thrown. I don't think `try/catch { do nothing }` (or `return String.Empty`) is valid here: it would be much better to let *an* exception escape, lest someone uses the function like `parameters.AddWithValue("@OldValue", CryptorEngine.Encrypt(oldValue))` -- if something bad occurs during `Encrypt` you'll store an empty value. Which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Yeah, I used to return "Invalid" string from exception block so, whenever I used this encrypt/decrypt method, I used to checked with return value....

Comment: Ok thanks, I´ve been googling but I cant find how to add the SecurityKey to web.config.

Comment: Ok, I found it. I was creating a new key every time.
Now I keep it in a static string in my class instead. 
I would like to store it in a SecurityKey in web.config, cannot find how to do that. Can you show me?

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt your data in .net with whatever encryption provider you like and store it in a column with the `VARBINARY` data type of the correct length.

For the rest treat the data the same as all other data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cast(s.TestCrypt AS varbinary) AS TestCrypt
```

That line [truncates the value of `TestCrypt` to 30 bytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx):

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When nis not specified with the CAST function, the default length is 30.

Try:

```
SELECT cast(s.TestCrypt AS varbinary(255)) AS TestCrypt
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I got another error that Im struggling with: 
Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.

Comment: @CliffSmith http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604210/padding-is-invalid-and-cannot-be-removed-using-aesmanaged

Comment: but it doesnt help. I have replaced both using but I havent done antything with the size, because it is not set anywhere